# currentSpec in Jasmine 2 is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, stub

I want to upgrade my test suite to the latest Jasmine version 2.3.4. I have some custom helper methods for testing AngularJS stuff inside my `spy_helper.js` like this:

```
(function() {
  this.stubPromise = function(service, functionName) {
    var $q = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.$injector.get("$q")
    var $rootScope = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.$injector.get("$rootScope")

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var spy = spyOn(service, functionName).andReturn(deferred.promise);
    spy.andResolveWith = function(value) {
      deferred.resolve(value);
      $rootScope.$apply();
      return spy;
    };
    spy.andRejectWith = function(value) {
      deferred.reject(value);
      $rootScope.$apply();
      return spy;
    };
    return spy;
  };
}).call(this);

// inside a test you can do
stubPromise(someService, 'foobar').andResolveWith("test");
```

The helper stubs a promise and immediately resolves or rejects the promise. I have a bunch of such helpers.

The problem with Jasmine 2 is, that `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec` is `undefined`. This is intended by the Jasmine 2 developers, as far as I know.

But how could I adapt my helpers for Jasmine 2? I could extend the arguments to get the `$injector` or even `$q` and `$rootScope`, but that would result in unhandy tests like `stubPromise(someService, 'foobar', $injector).andResolveWith("test");` AND you would have to inject the `$injector` on top of every test.

So, is there a way to get angular's `$injector` inside my helpers?

Furthermore in some other helpers, I need to catch the `after` method of a spec, to check if expected spies on promises where called `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.after(flush);`

Any help is appreciated, because those helpers saved me a lot of time, and I'd be not very happy to rewrite all of them or throw them out. Maybe there is also a library out there, which does something similar (and I didn't know it).

Comment: I still don't have a solution to this, so I sticked with jasmine 1, but if anybody comes across this questions and has a solution, please let me know