# Failed: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

**Snippet for taking screenshot on Test Failure**

```
    afterEach(function() {

        var spec = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec;
        var passed = spec.results().passed();

      if (!passed) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
          writeScreenShot(png, "screenshot.png");
        });
      }

        function writeScreenShot(data, filename) {
                var stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
                stream.write(new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
                stream.end();
        }

    });
```

**Console error**

```
  Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous>
```

---

it returns `undefined` here,

```
var spec = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec;
console.log(spec);
```

Looks like issues due to `Jasmine 2`; any alternate solutions also welcome! I use Jasmine 2

Comment: When exactly is this error occuring?!

Comment: @James111 There's only one place where a property `results` is being referenced...

Comment: @James111 AfterTest method used to be called after the test cases finish running

Comment: I'm getting error in this line var passed = spec.results().passed();

Comment: @usandfriends I went full retard and missed it! :')

Comment: It's because spec is null or doesn't have the .results object. Console.log(spec) and see what it's structure is like! It may be that something went wrong here `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec;` (most likely the case) @PrashanthSams

Comment: yea got it; let me check it.  1 sec pls

Comment: undefined is the output on giving console.log(spec)

Comment: Why it is undefined?

Comment: If your question is "Why is it undefined?", please add it to your post. At the moment, your post doesn't have a definite question...

Comment: Looks like `currentSpec` is [set when `specStarted` is called](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/314eb635520a75a3365c693007a53485aba5ad39/src/core/Env.js#L420). Maybe you're running into a race condition?

Comment: I see its due to the Jasmine version mismatch; not sure about the solution in Jasmine 2

Comment: I gave the snippet on start after the spec as well as on end of the tests; both results the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of `Jasmine 2.0`, `env.currentSpec` is no longer supported.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1212

Answer (score 0):

"var spec" is not being set to anything. That means "jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec" is not working for whatever reason.

Comment: something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198174/currentspec-in-jasmine-2-is-undefined